# Lucene Ful text search not search for Capital letters

Tags: lucene.net

I stuck with a problem for example if a search for an extended character "ÈÈÈ" it is not returning any search result If I search for only È it is not returning any result.

any solution?

Thanx

Answer (score 3):

May be the character È is eliminated during indexing. Check your analyzer. Most analyzers try remove the special characters during indexing.

Comment: Thanx for reply, if my analayzer is eliminating special character why it is giving result for È ?? and not for ÈÈÈ

Comment: @BreakHead, thats suspicious, could you please tell me which analyzer you are using...may be i can check in my environment...

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is a solution which worked for me

QueryParser.setLowercaseExpandedTerms(false);

it will not convert text to lowercase.

if you not set this to false parser will convert the seacrh text to small case and it will not return any result.